# Padding in header php wordpress site

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I would like to know what code to use in CSS to adjust the padding in my header area where the logo sits on my website 
[wwwsellingthailand}

Roughly i want to reduce the top and bottom white padding.Is there a way to do this or else i was looking at the option to get the logo to overlap on the top and bottom strip.

please advise.

regards
mark

Comment: Are you just trying to reduce the padding? Can you please reformulate your question. It's not very clear what you want to achieve

Comment: Basically I want to reduce the space at the top and bottom of the logo.if you look at the stackoverflow website there is roughly nothing at the top and bottom section in the header. Anyhow I have worked it out. I have tried #logo  {
Padding: 0px;

}

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your CSS settings:

```
#logo{
padding:0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Andril, It works.Thank you. wwwsellingthailand.com

Comment: @MarklovensAllam You are welcome. Vote this answer as right so it would be helpful for someone in the future.